# How can I get the actual height of the content,when -webkit-line-clamp: 2;-webkit-box-orient: vertical; and overflow:hidden is applied

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used two 'div's to explain my question both div **.text** and **text2** contains same data but **.text** has below CSS property:

```
.text {
   overflow: hidden;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

which text 2 has not, both has same data so but I want to know **.text** actual height even if above CSS applied.
**Second paragraph is just for reference I expect solution as the second paragraph is not there....**

```js
document.getElementById('text2').innerHTML = "Height of below div is: " + document.querySelector(".text2").offsetHeight;

document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Height of below div is: " + document.querySelector(".text").offsetHeight;
```

```css
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p id="text"></p>
  <div class="text">
    Et eirmod erat diam ipsum sit diam ut et est at ut tempor consequat nisl duis ut justo sit. Aliquyam adipiscing et esse consetetur dolores et suscipit stet magna invidunt sea et sadipscing ea at magna labore. Molestie dolores justo consetetur consequat.
    Sed sit aliquyam eirmod amet nonummy facilisis diam. Diam lorem dolores stet labore eos duo illum facer qui justo duo stet consetetur diam magna.
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <p id="text2"></p>
  <div class="text2">
    Et eirmod erat diam ipsum sit diam ut et est at ut tempor consequat nisl duis ut justo sit. Aliquyam adipiscing et esse consetetur dolores et suscipit stet magna invidunt sea et sadipscing ea at magna labore. Molestie dolores justo consetetur consequat.
    Sed sit aliquyam eirmod amet nonummy facilisis diam. Diam lorem dolores stet labore eos duo illum facer qui justo duo stet consetetur diam magna.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you like to get 114 for the first as well?

Comment: umm not sure, like on my screen it shows 90, but my expectation is to see actual content height like the second paragraph has the same content without CSS property of line clamp, so if in your screen second paragraph got 114 then yes, I am exactly looking for the first as well, thank you

Comment: I have been testing with a smaller viewport :) Never mind. I have written an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the `.text` `class` is present, the real size of the `div` becomes smaller. It is clear that you are interested in what would the size be if the `class` was not there, but in order to find that out, you need to do the measurement before you add the `class`, see the snippet below:

```js
let div1 = document.querySelector("#div1");
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Height of below div is: " + div1.offsetHeight;
div1.classList.add('text')
```

```css
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p id="text"></p>
  <div id="div1">
    Et eirmod erat diam ipsum sit diam ut et est at ut tempor consequat nisl duis ut justo sit. Aliquyam adipiscing et esse consetetur dolores et suscipit stet magna invidunt sea et sadipscing ea at magna labore. Molestie dolores justo consetetur consequat.
    Sed sit aliquyam eirmod amet nonummy facilisis diam. Diam lorem dolores stet labore eos duo illum facer qui justo duo stet consetetur diam magna.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I have just posted the second paragraph to explain what I am expecting, take it as we do not have the second paragraph there. HAHA wasn't thought of it

Comment: @stacknexo removed the second paragraph. Nevertheless, this seems to fulfill your expectation. If not, then please let me know what improvements are needed. If yes, then you might consider accepting this as the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry for mis understanding, your answer is correct thank you for your help

Comment: @stacknexo no worries, happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
.box {
display:grid;
grid-template-column:1fr 1fr;
align-items:stretch;
}
```

This Will Work for you.

Comment: How does this answer the question?